# Gamma function identities

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, stochastic-calculus

In the book Stochastic Geometry and Wireless Network vol.1 i found some equation that state : using the fact of

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^u}\mathrm{d}x = 1/u\Gamma[1/u]\Gamma[1-1/u] 
\end{equation}
where $u>0$

1. The question is how to prove this fact? or where can i start to prove this integral form equal to this Gamma function?
2. Is this only applied to interval $0 ~to~ \infty$ only? what if we define some interval from A to B (i.e A does not equal 0 and $B = \infty$)?

In [This Paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/39f3/5c06464f0779f8c49512155801b7903e92c5.pdf/%22this%20paper%22) i found a formula that almost similar

\begin{align}
I &=\int_b^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+w^{\alpha/2}}\mathrm{d}w\\ 
  &=\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\mathrm{csc}(2\pi/\alpha)-b_2F_1(1,2/\alpha;(2+\alpha)/\alpha;-b^{\alpha/2})
\end{align}

From this formula i try to expand the answer as follows

\begin{align}
I&=\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\frac{1}{sin(2\pi/\alpha)}-b_2F_1(1,2/\alpha;(2+\alpha)/\alpha;-b^{\alpha/2})\\
&=\frac{2}{\alpha}\Gamma(2/\alpha)\Gamma(1-2/\alpha)-b_2F_1(1,2/\alpha;(2+\alpha)/\alpha;-b^{\alpha/2})\\
&=\Gamma(1+2/\alpha)\Gamma(1-2/\alpha)-b_2F_1(1,2/\alpha;(2+\alpha)/\alpha;-b^{\alpha/2})\\
\end{align}

However from here i still cannot see how can i prove it from the original integral

Any comments are appreciated

Comment: Note that you should know what this is if $u = 2$. You should also note that if the interval is, say, finite, you'll get something completely different. Identities of a certain form must follow that form to hold.

Answer (score 0):

*May be an answer for the second part.*

If you consider $$I=\int\frac{dx}{1+x^u}$$ the result is given in terms of the gaussian or ordinary [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) $$I=x \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{u};1+\frac{1}{u};-x^u\right)$$ which can be integrated without any problem between any non negative bounds.

The particular case of $$J=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^u}=\frac{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)}{u}=\frac{\pi  }{u}\,\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{u}\right)$$ by [Euler reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (provided $u>1$).

Comment: Hi @Sean Roberson & Claude Leibovici ,  thank you for the comment, i updated the question, however since i'm not familiar yet with Hypergaussian, i still try to understand how to translate the integration into hypergeometric function

Comment: @m3wIsw3m. I think that you need to start from $J=\frac{\pi  }{u}\,\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{u}\right)$ and remember  Euler reflection formula

Comment: thank you so much for the input, I've found similar issue in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx), however haven't try it if the integral interval from X to $\infty$, i'll update it as soon as i figure it out, thank you once again